# Problems printing report with Report Viewer in Windows Form C# Application

Tags: c#, winforms, report, reportviewer, viewer

I have a problem with printing a report as the title suggests.
The report is always printed as in the picture, even if the report has the same dimensions as the A4 and the margins are set to 0in ... should the report not fill the A4 sheet?
Thank you in advance if anyone could help me.
[Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LlgG.png)

Comment: It doesn't look like you margins are set correctly.  Is the report a RDLC file.  If so it is html format and you should be able to open with a text editor and check where the origin and margins are located.

Comment: Check your printer and driver.  I've run into issues where either the printer didn't support the format requested or the driver was out of date.

Comment: right-click on your crystal report and go to page set up option then set margin